# Error building workspace of MoveIt 2 (Humble)

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I've been trying to build the workspace of MoveIt 2 with ROS 2 Humble. Following the tutorial, every time when I run **colcon build --mixin release** in the terminal, 2 packages always return the same error output, here is what I read in the shell:

```
Starting >>> moveit_common
Starting >>> srdfdom
Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_description
Starting >>> launch_param_builder
Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_description
Starting >>> moveit_task_constructor_msgs
Starting >>> moveit_resources_pr2_description
Starting >>> moveit_resources_prbt_support
Starting >>> rosparam_shortcuts
Finished <<< moveit_common [0.27s]                                   
Starting >>> rviz_marker_tools
Finished <<< moveit_resources_panda_description [0.29s]           
Starting >>> moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config
Finished <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_description [0.30s]
Finished <<< moveit_resources_prbt_support [0.30s]
Finished <<< moveit_resources_pr2_description [0.31s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config
Finished <<< rosparam_shortcuts [0.35s]
Finished <<< srdfdom [0.38s]
Finished <<< rviz_marker_tools [0.15s]                              
Finished <<< moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config [0.13s]
Starting >>> moveit_core
Finished <<< moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config [0.11s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources
Finished <<< moveit_resources [0.08s]                                
--- stderr: launch_param_builder                                     
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
---
Finished <<< launch_param_builder [0.64s]
Starting >>> moveit_configs_utils
Finished <<< moveit_task_constructor_msgs [0.79s]
Finished <<< moveit_core [0.47s]                                    
Starting >>> moveit_ros_occupancy_map_monitor
Starting >>> moveit_simple_controller_manager
Starting >>> moveit_resources_prbt_ikfast_manipulator_plugin
Starting >>> chomp_motion_planner
Starting >>> pilz_industrial_motion_planner_testutils
Finished <<< moveit_resources_prbt_ikfast_manipulator_plugin [0.12s] 
Finished <<< moveit_simple_controller_manager [0.15s]
Finished <<< pilz_industrial_motion_planner_testutils [0.14s]
Starting >>> moveit_plugins
Starting >>> moveit_ros_control_interface
Finished <<< chomp_motion_planner [0.16s]
Finished <<< moveit_ros_occupancy_map_monitor [0.18s]
Starting >>> moveit_chomp_optimizer_adapter
Starting >>> moveit_planners_chomp
Starting >>> moveit_ros_planning
Finished <<< moveit_plugins [0.10s]                                  
Finished <<< moveit_chomp_optimizer_adapter [0.13s]                  
Finished <<< moveit_ros_control_interface [0.18s]
Finished <<< moveit_planners_chomp [0.17s]
--- stderr: moveit_configs_utils
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
---
Finished <<< moveit_configs_utils [0.61s]
Finished <<< moveit_ros_planning [0.24s]                    
Starting >>> moveit_kinematics
Starting >>> moveit_ros_warehouse
Starting >>> moveit_ros_robot_interaction
Starting >>> moveit_planners_ompl
Starting >>> moveit_ros_perception
Starting >>> moveit_visual_tools
Finished <<< moveit_kinematics [0.18s]                                      
Starting >>> moveit_ros_move_group
Finished <<< moveit_ros_robot_interaction [0.20s]
Finished <<< moveit_visual_tools [0.20s]
Finished <<< moveit_ros_warehouse [0.22s]
Starting >>> moveit_ros_benchmarks
Finished <<< moveit_ros_perception [0.23s]
Finished <<< moveit_planners_ompl [0.25s]
Finished <<< moveit_ros_benchmarks [0.14s]
Finished <<< moveit_ros_move_group [0.20s]                    
Starting >>> moveit_ros_planning_interface
Starting >>> moveit_resources_prbt_moveit_config
Finished <<< moveit_resources_prbt_moveit_config [0.07s]
Starting >>> moveit_resources_prbt_pg70_support
Finished <<< moveit_ros_planning_interface [0.14s]
Starting >>> moveit_ros_visualization
Starting >>> moveit_task_constructor_core
Starting >>> moveit_hybrid_planning
Starting >>> moveit_servo
Finished <<< moveit_resources_prbt_pg70_support [0.09s]
Starting >>> pilz_industrial_motion_planner
Finished <<< moveit_hybrid_planning [0.26s]                                    
Finished <<< moveit_task_constructor_core [0.30s]
Starting >>> moveit_task_constructor_capabilities
Finished <<< moveit_servo [0.35s]      
Finished <<< pilz_industrial_motion_planner [0.36s]
Starting >>> moveit_planners
Finished <<< moveit_task_constructor_capabilities [0.12s]
Starting >>> moveit_task_constructor_demo
Finished <<< moveit_ros_visualization [0.47s]
Starting >>> moveit_setup_framework
Starting >>> moveit_ros
Starting >>> moveit_task_constructor_visualization
Finished <<< moveit_planners [0.09s]
Starting >>> moveit_runtime
Finished <<< moveit_ros [0.11s]        
Finished <<< moveit_runtime [0.10s]
Finished <<< moveit_task_constructor_demo [0.20s]
Finished <<< moveit_setup_framework [0.18s]                                    
Starting >>> moveit_setup_app_plugins
Starting >>> moveit_setup_controllers
Starting >>> moveit_setup_core_plugins
Starting >>> moveit_setup_srdf_plugins
Finished <<< moveit_task_constructor_visualization [0.32s]
Finished <<< moveit_setup_core_plugins [0.20s]
Finished <<< moveit_setup_app_plugins [0.23s]
Finished <<< moveit_setup_controllers [0.28s]
Finished <<< moveit_setup_srdf_plugins [0.30s]                    
Starting >>> moveit_setup_assistant
Finished <<< moveit_setup_assistant [0.15s]                      
Starting >>> moveit
Finished <<< moveit [0.08s]                  
Starting >>> moveit2_tutorials
Finished <<< moveit2_tutorials [0.15s]                    

Summary: 55 packages finished [3.46s]
  2 packages had stderr output: launch_param_builder moveit_configs_utils
```

Dose anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411686/error-building-workspace-of-moveit-2-(humble)/) by [Jonas_Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/135127/jonas_z/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2023-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
stderr is a common output in ROS2 when building. usually, it doesn't mean it hasn't built properly and is often related to displaying certain warnings and messages.
So, in most cases - you should be able to use whatever you built without any issues.

---

Originally posted by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) with karma: 87 on 2023-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jonas_Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/135127/jonas_z/) on 2023-01-23**:
Understood. Thank you so much for your answer!

**Comment by [AibohphobiA](https://answers.ros.org/users/57608/aibohphobia/) on 2023-01-24**:
Would appreciate if you mark it answered. have a good one.

**Comment by [Jonas_Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/135127/jonas_z/) on 2023-01-24**:
Done. You too, have a good one!